# How to send URL (with vars in it) as a single var?

Tags: php, ajax, urlvariables

I have a url string like this:

```
http://www.google.com/cse?cx=017840637368510444960:ny1lmky7r-0&client=google-csbe&output=xml_no_dtd&q=simon+g
```

I need to send this url from ajax to a php script as a single string variable.

I am having trouble though because it keeps getting split into several vars because of the vars in the url string itself. Make sense? How can I send this as a single string??

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to encode it.

In PHP: [`urlencode()`](http://www.php.net/urlencode)

```
$str = urlencode('http://....');
```

In Javascript: encodeURIComponent

```
str = encodeURIComponent('http://...');
```

Comment: Hmm... if you're passing it though in GET or POST then PHP should decode it for you.

Answer (score 4):

You need to [urlencode](https://www.php.net/urlencode) the url.  You will then [urldecode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) on the page that receives it.

So the url would become

```
http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fcse%3Fcx%3D017840637368510444960%3Any1lmky7r-0%26client%3Dgoogle-csbe%26output%3Dxml_no_dtd%26q%3Dsimon%2Bg%0D%0A
```

Answer (score 1):

`escape()` or `encodeURIComponent()`

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to escape() in javascript like this

escape("cx=017840637368510444960:ny1lmky7r-0&client=google-csbe&output=xml_no_dtd&q=simon+g"
)

**Edit:** I just searched and found that encodeURIComponent() is the best solution.

See http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/encode-compare/ for a nice comparison of escape(), encodeURI() and encodeURIComponent()

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
// In your URL-emitter page
$decoded_url = "http://www.google.com/cse?cx=017840637368510444960:ny1lmky7r-0&client=google-csbe&output=xml_no_dtd&q=simon+g";
$link_addr = "/index.php?encodedurl=".urlencode($decoded_url);

echo '<a href="'.$link_addr.'">Click me</a>';


// in your URL-reciever page (here the same page)
if(array_key_exists("encodedurl",$_GET)) {
    echo 'decoded url='.urldecode($_GET["encodedurl"]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

also, you could try encryption (like base64)

Comment: Right, not encryption. And... heh.. third-party base64 on JS to encode URL... why?

Comment: @Tahir Akthar; you are right, my bad!
I read the post all wrong, and added a stupid answer :)